# Can't get all the information I need from the Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FBSDK v2.4 to authorise and collect information about the user. Here is the code:

```
   private class func gatherUserData()
        {
            let parameters = ["fields": "id, about, birthday, email, first_name, gender, hometown, is_verified, last_name, locale, religion, timezone"]
            let manager = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters, HTTPMethod: "GET")
            manager.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    SocialParcer.parseFacebook(result)
                }
                else {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

but I am getting this instead (actual data replaced):

```
{
    "first_name" = "Name";
    gender = male;
    id = "id";
    "is_verified" = 0;
    "last_name" = "Last Name";
    locale = "en_US";
    timezone = 5;
}
```

As you can see, more than a half of parameters aren't present. How can I access them?

Comment: You need to ask the user for the appropriate permissions first – did you do that …?

Comment: @CBroe Ops, I thinks this is it. I didn't think about permissions, authorisation code was written by another programmer. Thank you!

Comment: I was going to suggest 2 things, either permissions or the user might not have entered them. `religion` for example I don't think is required to setup an account